# You're from which country or which country you're from

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, questions, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

**1.You're going to school?**

**2.You're from which country?**

Are their structures grammatical? I think they're supposed to be:

(1) *Are you going to school?*

(2) *Which country are you from?*

So which ones are correct? When to use which form?

Comment: The first one is a [statement used as a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/statements-used-as-questions-in-casual-speech).

Comment: What about 2 &(2)? Do they mean the same? My one more question is that which is preferable between "You love me?" and "Do you love me?"

Comment: Or [forming a question without inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204339/can-i-ask-a-question-without-inversion-as-in-you-are-fine)  In  short,  these questions are sometimes used to check for confirmation, not as normal questions.

Comment: As James says, you would only use No. 2 if you had already been told what country the person came from and wanted to be reminded, or were surprised and wanted them to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forming a question by intonation (or typographically inserting a questionmark) is possible but rare.  It tends to be used to check for confirmation, rather than a simple request for information.

"You're going to school?"  might mean  "Are you really going to school today?"  And used in a situation in which it seems that the person is going to school, but you think that they shouldn't

Nearly all the time you should form questions by inversion "Are you going...."

Answer (score 1):

grammatically speaking, (1) and (2) are more preferable and are the ones we choose in formal writing.
1 and 2 are correct too. They are commonly used in casual speaking or informal writing and they mostly are used when the speaker knows the answer to the question and wants to show that he/she is surprised or wants to make sure of the answer.